# This dictionary requires a model item of type 'Umbraco.Web.Models.PartialViewMacroModel'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I have the following Partial View: (/Views/Partials/Banner.cshtml)

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<MyProject.Models.Banner>

<div class="test">@Model.Title</div>
```

And this Model: (/Models/Banner.cs)

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Banner
    {
        public string Title;

        public Banner(string title = "")
        {
            Title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

I try to include my Partial view in one of my layouts using the following code:

```
@Html.Partial("Banner", new MyProject.Models.Banner("TestBanner"))
```

and I get the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'MyProject.Models.Banner', but this dictionary requires a model item
>   of type 'Umbraco.Web.Models.PartialViewMacroModel'.

I have also tried using `@model MyProject.Models.Banner` instead of `@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<MyProject.Models.Banner>` in my Partial View with the exact same result.

I had believed that Umbraco.RenderMacro() was used for rendering MacroPartials (which I believe PartialViewMacroModel relates to) and standard Html.Partial() would allow me to render my partial view with a model of my choosing. Could somebody please inform me of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

YM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that another member of my team had created a Banner.cshtml file in /Views/MacroPartials and this Partial View was being loaded instead of my one.